# How to extend default user mode to have additional properties?

Tags: cofoundry

I have checked the samples and read the documentation but did not get an idea on how we can customize or extend the default user management with our custom fields and some custom buttons in there to extend the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Cofoundry does not currently support extensions to the user table, the feature is tracked by issue [#176](https://github.com/cofoundry-cms/cofoundry/issues/176).

Comment: any guestimate onto when it will be available?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/716689/joel-mitchell
is there a way we can disable the email update from backend for a custom user area?

Comment: can you please update if you know or have information handy?